# jQuery .serialize() is sending the default input values, not updated

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I've created a simple form and jQuery plugin to submit the form to a PHP script which will add it to a database. Shouldn't be a big deal, however, jQuery's .serialize() is submitting the form with the default input values, rather than the values the user typed.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id="submit-assignment" method="post" action="URL-HERE">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="class_id">
    <div id="assignment-title-parent" style="width: 367px;">
    <input id="assignment-title" class="new-name" type="text" value="Name a new assignment." style="border-right: 0pt none; height: 14px;" name="assignment-title">
    <div id="assignmentadd-step2" class="btn leftflat next-right" style="height: 14px;">Next »</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="assignment-desc-parent" class="hidden">
    <textarea id="assignment-desc" class="new-desc" name="assignment-desc" style="">Describe this assignment here. Include directions, resources, etc.</textarea>
    <div style="width: 310px;">
    <div id="assignmentadd-step3" class="btn fr" style="margin-top: 2px;">Next »</div>
    <div class="fl txt-small txt-gray top6">
    <input id="assignment-date" class="new-date hasDatepicker" type="text" value="When is it due?" name="assignment-date">
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="assignment-preview-parent" class="hidden">
    </form>
```

And the Plugin:

```
jQuery.fn.submitForm = function(callback) {      

    $(this).submit(function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
            //alert($(this).serialize());
           $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {   

                if(typeof callback == 'function'){
                     callback.call(this, data);
                }

            }, 'json');
    });
};
```

And the Plugin Usage:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit-assignment').submitForm(function() { 
        //-> callback...
    });     
});
```

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Also, http://jsfiddle.net/Rcqry/ I can't seem to replicate this problem of yours.

Comment: @Calvin I'm just calling the plugin with `$('#submit-assignment').submitForm(function(){});`and the plugin waits for .submit() to be called. That all works fine, it's just something to do with .serialize() sending the default input values.

Comment: They will definitely send the default values if at the point of submission the input was defaulted to e.g. value="Name a new assignment.". What you probably want to do instead is something like placeholder="Name a new assignment."

Answer (score 0):

Serialize will take whatever value of all input fields in the form to submit. If you intend them as placeholders you can do as follows:

```
<input name="assignment-title" value="" placeholder="placeholder text goes here" />
```

Also, placeholders are HTML5, so for my own personal preference I create a function to work as a placeholder fallback. I've edited the jsfiddle.net for an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rcqry/